# A doubt regarding Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

Classically when we solve Newton's equation for $V=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$ we get two linearly independent solutions (for $\omega\not=0$): $Ae^{\omega t}$ & $Be^{-\omega t}$, their linear combinations would also be a solution.

In Griffith's QM book (pg 51, 3rd ed.) he says that the time independent Schrodinger equation has *two* linearly independent solutions for any value of $E$. Does this mean than every $E$ is doubly degenerate? What even are these two solutions? I only know how to write one $\psi(x)$ for normalizable states. This is not as obvious to me as the classical case.

Comment: Can you take a quote of the main part?

Answer (score 3):

At most  one of the two solutions can be  normalizable, and therefore an element of the Hibert space. And only a discrete set $E_n=\omega(n+1/2)$  of energies has a normalizable solution.

Comment: Could you please write down the expression for both the solutions. Are they simply $Ae^{\xi^2/2}$ and $Be^{-\xi^2/2}$? After this the author proceeds to discard the former as it diverges and then he uses power series to derive those normalizeable $\psi(x)$s (the hermite ones).